# Access dom of the doc/docx in App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Is there a way to access the **dom** of the active document(doc/docx) in google app script? I only managed to get the body of the document as text.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063246/getting-the-javascript-document-html-dom-info-within-google-apps-script) which suggested to use the [`XML service`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/#parse) that allows scripts to parse, navigate, and programmatically create XML documents. Here's an additional reference which might also help: [Does Google Apps Script have something like getElementById?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695034/does-google-apps-script-have-something-like-getelementbyid)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I already tried that one. I found a workaround to get and parse the text as a string. The only problem that I have now is that the getCursor() function returns only the position of the cursor in the current row. (I'm on row 3 and at position 54 it will only return 54, nothing about the row to be able to get all the text before the cursor position)